# Symfony2 and setter injection

Tags: symfony

I am sure this question has already been asked, but I am out of options and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I am using Symfony2, and I am creating a form builder with a Data Transformer.
I am trying a setter injection inside the Data Transformer.

The reason I need a setter injection is that the transformers already needs a parameter to be passed manually to the constructor. I wanted to keep an approach as clean as possible and avoid passing too much stuff by hand.

Here is the code of my Data Transformer:

```
  // src/MyBundle/Form/DataTransformer/MyTransformer.php
  namespace MyBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

  use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

  use MyBundle\Entity\UserRepository;

  class MyTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
  {

    /**
      * @var EntityManager
      */
      private $entityManager;

      private $user;

      public function setEntityManager(
             \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager
      )
      {
          echo "Debug: Check-in setEntityManager!";
          $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
      }

      public function __construct($user)
      {
          echo "Debug: Check-in __construct!";
          $this->user = $user;
      }
// ....
```

And this is my config.yml

```
  mybundle.form.mytransformer:
      class: MyBundle\Form\DataTransformer\MyTransformer
      calls:
          - [setEntityManager, ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]]
```

As I can see from my echoes, constructor is called, while setEntityManager is not.
What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help me?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet the output from the setter is being squelched somehow. Have you tried pulling your service from the container and seeing if the entitymanager property is set as expected?

Comment: Your posted service configuration does not have an arguments section?  I don't see how the constructor can be called unless it was a copy/paste error OR you have the same service defined somewhere else?  And of course you are using the data transformer as a service and not using new MyTransformer() somewhere?

Comment: I am willing to bet that you have a new MyTransformer($user) statement inside of a FormType and that you expected the container would automatically the entity manager?  Not going to happen.  You need to inject the data transformer into your form type.

Comment: @phpisuber01 I do not understand what you mean with "pulling your service from the container". If I use _$this->entityManager->getRepository(..)_ inside my functions, I get _Error: Call to a member function getRepository() on a non-object_

Comment: @Cerad the constructor works ok because I pass the parameter by hand, i.e. I create the transformer as _$transformer = new MyTransformer($user);_
This is the rason why I need a separate setter. Anyway, I tried also to pass only the entityManager from the controller (commented _$user_ and where I was using it) and still does not work.

Comment: @Cerad You mean that I cannot have both a parameter passed to the constructor and a setter injection from config? Thought it would be straightforward... Thanks you all for your answers!

Comment: Yep.  That is exactly what I mean.  The new operator has no relation with the service container.  Probably want to do a bit of research since you won't get very far with Symfony 2 without understanding services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html